# CSS two background images doesn't fit on mobile devices

Tags: css, image, background, pixel

i want to put two image backgrounds pixel perfect next to each other. This works perfekt on desktop but not on mobile.

example:

```css
    .header{      
        background: url(https://stammalanen.de/wp-content/themes/alanen/images/mapHeaderBg.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
      height: 216px;
    }
    .main{
        background: url(https://stammalanen.de/wp-content/themes/alanen/images/mapContentBg.jpg);
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
      height: 257px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="main"></div>
    </div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o69z3qmx/1/)
check it on debugger by switching to mobile view.

result:
there is a thin line
[image]

so, how to fit this boath perfect also on mobile devices?

Comment: use `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 0):

You could make the wrapper class a black background so the image can blend in.

Try this.

```
    .header{      
        background: url(https://stammalanen.de/wp-content/themes/alanen/images/mapHeaderBg.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 216px;
        background-position: center bottom;
        background-size: contain;
    }

    .main{
        background: url(https://stammalanen.de/wp-content/themes/alanen/images/mapContentBg.jpg);
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        height: 257px;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: contain;
    }

    .wrapper{
        background-color: #000;
    }

    @media(max-width: 767px){
        .wrapper{
            margin-top: -100px;
        }
    }
```